# Such small room we had, is it correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, subjects

**Such small room, we had.**
I know you can say (we had such small rooms, but in some situations it just feels more correct when you put the subject and (had/have) in the end.
If this is wrong then how is there any other way to say this sentence?

Comment: This phrase is written in the same way Yoda from Star Wars speaks in the English version of the movies. To native speakers, odd it might sound ;)

Comment: An alternative way to say this: "Our room was so small" or "We had such a small room".

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the text, you meant to ask about *Such small room**s** we had*, yes?

Yes, you can front the object for emphasis. There's a (very short) account in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_clause_syntax#Fronting_and_zeroing).

You would not normally use a comma before the subject, because the sentence is one breath group. If you inserted a comma (end of breath group) after "rooms", that makes the "We had" sound like an afterthought.

Comment: To add on to this, it is sometimes stylistically acceptable to use the comma where it is precisely to give the “we had” at the end the air of an afterthought. However, this is more of a question of writing style.